Reliably compress a string of 1s and 0s into a smaller string, and convert it back to the Exact same string. Everytime
I was wondering if there is a better way to do this in NodeJS or plain javascript.
I wrote some functions that can do this by counting how many times they repeat, but i was wondering if there is a better way, or if theres any improvements to be made.
The input will always be a 256 bit number string consisting only of 1s and 0s ('00001110100101.....')
function toSmallString(x) { // {{{
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // always start with a 0 or a 1 to show bigstring where to start
    var nn = `${x[0]}`;
    var ar = x.split('')
    var n = 0;
    var lv = ar[0];

    // a blank item to iterate, catches the last set of numbers
    ar.push('')

    // 0 means ten and continue since we will always be above 1
    for (const v of ar) {
      // if flipping bits, store number and start over
      if (lv !== v) { nn += n ;lv = v; n = 1 }

      // increment if last value is same as this value, if value becomes 10, add a 0 to nn and start over
      else { n = n + 1;if(n === 10){nn += '0';n = 0} }
    }
    resolve(nn)
  })
}

function toBigString(x) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var ar = x.split('')
    var sn = parseInt(ar.shift())
    var nn = ''

        // 0 means 10 zeros and continue without bitflipping
        // any other number will expand and then flip bits

    for (const v of ar) {
      var n = parseInt(v)
      var i = 1
      if(n === 0){
        nn += sn.toString().repeat(10)
      } else {
        while(i <= n){
          nn += sn
          i = i + 1
        }
        // bit flip
        sn = (sn === 0) ? 1 : 0;
      }
    }
    resolve(nn)
  })
}

I tried a couple things, im very inexperienced (hexadecimal, scientific notation) but the values would change form when trying to convert it back to the original 256 bits of 1s and 0s.
each 1 and 0 is important, their placing and order is vital to preserve.
My plan is to store hundreds of thousands of these 256 bit strings, so a form of string conpression would be the way to go.
Edit:
Here is a list of ~7k Input Strings

im very inexperienced — understand that data compression schemes have been an area of extremely active research for 40 years at least. It's nice that you want to do some interesting stuff, but there is an enormous amount of existing work out there to look at.  Check Wikipedia for example under "data compression".

now that I think of it, more like 70 or 80 years.

@Pointy my compression algorithm turned out to be a little better for this specific use case. Thank you for your effort

A simple solution could be to use a BigInt (which can safely represent a 256-bit number), then convert it to a hex string.
function toSmallString(x) {
  return BigInt('0b' + x).toString(16); // bin => hex
}
function toBigString(x) {
  return BigInt('0x' + x).toString(2).padStart(256, '0'); // hex => bin
}


You could use an even higher radix (up to 36) to make it potentially even shorter.

Thank You, However After using this ~7k times, there were ~5k instances where the decompressed number no longer matched. here is a csv list of cases where they did not match. the values are in this order 'original|compressed|decompressed'. I am updating the original post to include the full list of ~7k

@RadicalEdward Right, it was stripping the leading zeros. Fixed now.

@AHaworth I thought about this, but it seems like there's no parseInt equivalent for BigInt where you can specify a radix. Only an old proposal for one...

Update
i have expanded upon @Nikk's solution and decided to use a hexadecimal-like format
The goal is to get the shortest string possible from a string that will only contain a range of digits (originally 0-1 , but in this example well do 1-8)
I defined a charactermap that contains all possible 2 digit combinations from 11 to 88 (11..18,21..28,31.......88) that maps it to a single character, there are 64 possible combinations in this range (8^2=64)
so with all possible combinations our final characterset became [a-zA-Z!-_] without any numbers
our length goes from 256 to 128
id be interested to try mapping larger sets of digits to unicode
characters to get shorter results but wed need a much, much larger
charactermap.
since our characterset has no numbers, we can then switch repeating characters with a single character and a digit to denote how many times that character repeats.
since our digit will always be 1 and up, we can say a 0 means 10 and place another digit afterwards until they sum to the exact repitition.
so this means our digits 0.... and 1.... become a4 and b4
40 repitions of 1 become a0000 ('0' * 10 to the 4th power)
100 repitions of 1 become a0000000000 ('0' * 10 to the 10th power)
256 0s would be a00000000000000000000000006 which is a string thats 27 bits long
so with this approach, our resulting string from 256 bits will range anywhere from 27-128 bits.
we could get shorter by replacing the repeating 0s for a set of unicode values since its a larger characterset, making the shortest string look something like "a0|6"
"a0|6" means 256 0s in a row, however we could just store a single digit and repeat it 256 times when reverting in the case that all digits match.
So the shortest string ranges anywhere from either 1,4bits to 128bits from 256 digits with the shorter strings only possible if you have more than 4 repeated digits in the string. (which i do very commonly)
here is the code for base8 (1-8) string compression
function allCharactersSame(s){
  let n = s.length;
  for (let i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    if (s[i] != s[0]) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
const characterMap = { // {{{
'11':'a','12':'b','13':'c','14':'d','15':'e','16':'f','17':'g','18':'h','21':'i','22':'j','23':'k','24':'l','25':'m','26':'n','27':'o','28':'p','31':'q','32':'r','33':'s','34':'t','35':'u','36':'v','37':'w','38':'x','41':'y','42':'z','43':'A','44':'B','45':'C','46':'D','47':'E','48':'F','51':'G','52':'H','53':'I','54':'J','55':'K','56':'L','57':'M','58':'N','61':'O','62':'P','63':'Q','64':'R','65':'S','66':'T','67':'U','68':'V','71':'W','72':'X','73':'Y','74':'Z','75':'!','76':'@','77':'#','78':'$','81':'%','82':'^','83':'&','84':'*','85':'(','86':')','87':'-','88':'_'
} // }}}
async function convertHash(string) { // {{{
    if(allCharactersSame(string)){
        return string[0]
    }
    if(string.length % 2 === 1){throw 'Input MUST be fully divisable by 2'}
    var n = ''
    // map characters
    string.match(/.{1,2}/g).forEach((num) => {n += characterMap[num]})
    // shrink repeats
    string = n.replace(/(.)\1+/g, (s) => {
        var nn = ''
        var x = Math.floor(s.length / 10)
        var y = s.length % 10
        nn += '0'.repeat(x)
        if (y !== 0){nn += y}
        return `${s[0]}${nn}`
    })
    return string
} // }}}
async function revertHash(string) { // {{{
    if(string.length === 1){
        return string.repeat(256)
    }

    // unshrink
    var nn = string.replaceAll(/([a-zA-Z])([0-9]+)/g,function(s1){
        var ny = ''
        var v = '';
        var ar = s1.split('')
        var ch = ar.shift()
        for(v of ar) {
            if(v === '0'){
                ny += ch.repeat(10)
            } else {
                ny += ch.repeat(v)
            }
        }
        return ny
    })

    // unpack
    var n = ''
    nn.split('').forEach(bit => {
        Object.keys(characterMap).forEach(key => {
            if (bit === characterMap[key]) {
                n += key
            }
        })
    })
    return n
} // }}}

Using this i compressed ~7k 256 bit base2 numberstrings to an average of 86 bits with ~30 of them becoming single bit lengths with 100% accuracy when decompressing.
